# (PHP) Display link ONLY during business hours?

Tags: php, time

I am trying to make a live chat link appear on the website **only** during business hours. I have the code below which seems to work in the afternoon, but won't work in the morning and I'm not sure why... `$start` and `$end` are values received from a MySQL database but in my example I've hard coded them to make the example simpler.

```
$LinkStatus = "on";

$start = 9:00:00;
$end = 23:00:00;
$current_time = date('G:i:s'); //9:35:00

if (($start > $current_time) || ($end < $current_time)) {
    $LinkStatus = "off"; 
}
```

If the start time is greater than the current time, then the business is not open yet. If the end time is less than the current time, then it's after hours. Any time between 9am and 11pm (23:00) neither one of those conditions should be true, therefore `$LinkStatus` should remain `"on"`. However, it does not seem to be doing that right now. Something is setting it to `"off"`.

I've echoed the variable above the if statement and below it so I can confirm it's this if statement causing the variable to be set to `"off"`.

As you can probably see from my code example, I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to PHP. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The logic of your if statement is incorrect; it will show off if the time is before 11pm, OR after 9am. Which means it will always show 'off'. You need to re-write it so it shows 'off' if it's before 9am or after 11pm.

Comment: if 9:00:00 is greater than 9:35:00 or if 23:00:00 is less than 9:35:00, the linkstatus will be off. Since neither of those statements are true at this point, I fail to see how it will always be "off". If 9:35:00 was changed to 8:35, the first condition would be true and the variable would be set to "off". Same if the time was set to 23:01:00. I fail to see how this is flawed. Sorry I am still not very skilled at PHP.

Comment: An OR statement is true if either criteria is true. In this case, any time after 9am will be true, because of the first check. If it's 9:00:01, or 23:59:59, it's after than 9:00:00, so it's true - the only times that won't pass that first check are ones before 9:00:00. But the second check will return true if the time is before 23:00:00; and so any time before 9:00:00 will return true there, because 8:59:59 _is_ before 23:00:00. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Perhaps I should do the exact opposite then? `if (($start < $current_time) && $end > $current_time)) $LinkStatus = "on"; else $LinkStatus = "off"` If I understand that correctly, $LinkStatus is on during business hours, otherwise, it's off?

Comment: I think that will work, yes; I'd swap around the conditions, as I find it a little easier to read: `if (($current_time >= $start) && $current_time <= $end))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date('G:i:s')  // 24 hours time without leading zero for hour
```

...won't sort well as a string, for example '9' > '10'.

Use 24 hour time with a leading zero instead, which makes the correct sort '09' < '10';

```
date('H:i:s')  // 24 hour time with leading zero for hour
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. As I posted this question the local time here became 10:00 and suddenly my code was working. I implemented your suggestion and set the clock back to 9:00 and it still works!

Answer (score 0):

```html
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
  $day_start = '09:00:00';
  $day_end = '16:59:59';
  $current_time = date('H:i:s'); // For 9-5 hours only
  $current_day = date('N'); // For Monday to Friday only
  if (($current_day <= 5) && ($current_time >= $day_start) && ($current_time <= $day_end)) {
     echo 'ON'; 
  } else {
    echo 'OFF'
  }
```