# Webpage open only during certain hours of the day

Tags: time, html

How can I make a webpage open only during certain hours of the day in a given timezone? I'm using Wix, as I am not smart enough to learn any kind of legitimate programming.

Comment: Trivially, in any actual web framework. In wix? Dunno, and I suspect you should [ask them](http://www.wix.com/about/contact-us)

Comment: Do you mean that you want your site open only when it's, say office hours in London, or do you want it open for a visitor when it's office hours in their location? The former will have your site open all night in New Zealand, the latter is pointless, since it'll always be office hours somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't think that's possible with something like Wix since they usually have set-in-stone templates. Most website creation sites I know don't allow you to add custom code, and as a matter of fact it might be taken literally as part of their motto:

"Easy to customize. No coding."

Also, just to clarify I signed up for Wix and checked it out...

In short, I don't think that's possible. You'd need something like Javascript/PHP to accomplish that. You wouldn't be able to use HTML blocks or a Flash file (.swf) and those are the closest kinds of customizations (drag and drop blocks) they offer for your site that would get you there.

I would look into hiring someone to design it or buying a program like Rapidweaver (which is what I use) to create a website on a domain you already own.

Comment: Also, this question might help you out, I saw it in related: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727087/php-display-link-only-during-business-hours?rq=1)